# How to get Distinct values in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem in my SQL Query

i want to select DISTINCT StudentGroups(SG) but the query gives me some repetations

here is my Query

```
SELECT      DISTINCT(SG.SGID), en.EnrollmentID, CR.Name AS Course, INS.Name as Instructor,
                S.Session, SG.StartTime, SG.EndTime, EN.CreateDate

    FROM        StudentGroups SG inner JOIN Enrollments EN ON SG.SGID = EN.SGID
                JOIN Courses CR ON SG.CourseID = CR.CourseID
                JOIN Class CL ON SG.ClassID = CL.ClassID
                JOIN Instructors INS ON SG.InstructorID = INS.InstructorID
                JOIN Sessions S ON SG.SessionID = S.SessionID

    WHERE       EN.SGID NOT IN ( SELECT SGID FROM Enrollments
                            WHERE StudentID = 45
```

**UPDATED**

This query gives me following data

[image]

but i don't want repeated SGID

Comment: `DISTINCT` is ***not*** a function. It's an *operator* applied to **all** columns in the select list.

Comment: DISTINCT works on the **whole** row: you can't get DISTINCT SGID values in the same result set with other columns. It makes no sense...

Comment: then how can i get unique records?? @a_horse_with_no_name ,@gbn

Comment: Unique according to what? It would help if you showed us some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting your output to be here?  You are joining multiple tables together, so unless your relationships between tables are all 1-1, you can expect some repetition in your resulting data set.  If you could give an example of how you would like your output to look, that would be helpful.

Comment: You need to tell us *how* to pick one of the rows. How do you determine which row should be discarded and which one you want to keep? The latest? The first?

Comment: Do you need the EnrollmentID/CreateDate in your result?  If so, you're going to have to either aggregate those values and use a GROUP BY on the remaining columns, or accept the repetition of SGID, as there are multiple records in Enrollment for each StudentGroup.

Comment: The edit to your question doesn't help. If you don't want SGID repeated (but there is more than one row for each), what criteria should decide which row to show?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`DISTINCT` always applies to all columns returned.  Putting parentheses around one column makes no difference in its behavior.

If you want your results to contain only unique values of `SG.GID`, you can use a `GROUP BY` clause instead--but then *you have to decide some rules for which values you want to return* in the other columns. You do this by using aggregate functions like `MIN()`,`MAX()`,`COUNT()`,`SUM()`, etc. Simplified example:

```
SELECT  SG.SGID,
        MIN(SG.START_TIME),              --the lowest start time for this sgid.
        COUNT(DISTINCT en.EnrollmentID)  --the unique enrollments for this sgid.
    FROM StudentGroups SG 
    INNER JOIN Enrollments EN ON SG.SGID = EN.SGID
    GROUP BY SG.SGID;
```

When joining multiple tables as in your original query, you have to be careful when counting and summing things, as duplicates from the join can give you incorrect results.

Another option would be to use `ROW_NUMBER()` to return one row for each `SGID`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT  SG.SGID,
            SG.START_TIME, 
            en.EnrollmentID,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SGID ORDER BY SG.START_TIME) as RN
        FROM StudentGroups SG 
        INNER JOIN Enrollments EN ON SG.SGID = EN.SGID
    )
    WHERE RN = 1;
```

This numbers the rows for each `SGID`, starting at 1 and sorted by the value of `SG.START_TIME`.  It will return the one row with the earliest start time for each `SGID`. If multiple rows have the same start time, it will select any one of those, more or less at random.  You could add more fields to the `ORDER BY` clause to further define which rows are returned.

Answer (score 6):

Please use GROUP BY clause when DISTINCT is not working for your desired output.